# Multiline TreeView Nodes

Tags: vb.net, treeview, nodes

Visual Studio 2010
Visual Basic .NET

I have a TreeView control (tvLOC)
Some of the nodes in tvLOC are too long and require side scrolling. 
With a little string concatenation, I have the node split at a break and the inserted vbCrLf.

Now my problem is, I cannot manage to get the second line to show. 
I have tried drawing a rectangle and I also tried changing the node height.
Nothing seems to be working for me and I also get a redraw issue where any of the nodes that are multiline, if you click on one it redraws the node at the top of tvLOC.

Here is my DrawNode code

```
 Dim nodeFont As Font = e.Node.NodeFont

 If nodeFont Is Nothing Then
     nodeFont = CType(sender, TreeView).Font
 End If

 Dim testingString As String = e.Node.Text

 If testingString.Length > 60 Then

     Dim hold As String = testingString.Substring(0, 60)
     hold = hold.Substring(0, hold.LastIndexOf(" "))
     testingString = testingString.Replace(hold, "")
     testingString = hold & vbCrLf & testingString

     e.Graphics.DrawString(testingString, nodeFont, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Top + 1)

 Else

     e.Graphics.DrawString(testingString, nodeFont, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Top + 1)

 End If
```

Comment: That cannot work, what you draw is clipped by the Bounds of the tree node.  It isn't tall enough for the font you are using.  Alternatives are not pretty, you have to use a fake point size for the node font to get enough room vertically.  But that also makes it too wide.  Which in turn requires you to use a fake Text property.  Boilerplate is to use a tooltip to make clipped text in a node visible.  Or to use one of the "TreeList" custom controls that you can get from component vendors.

Comment: The last node in the TreeView is too long so I have it set to split, and that one shows the second line, but there is nothing else below.  So Basically I just need to know if there is a way to expand the height of nodes that are longer than 60 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently what I am looking to do is not possible.
Nothing I have been able to find out there has lead me to believe this can be done.